# How soon should I replant a grocery store rose

Tags: containers, roses

[image]

Brought this guy home. Is there guidelines on when best to repot if I want this to live inside, on a southern facing Midwestern window sill.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a varietal name on the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, well thanks for adding a picture of the label,but its not very informative, doesn't give a varietal name. It does suggest this is a mini rose, but that's not really a guide as to size.

I'm sorry to say that this plant will likely be a temporary visitor to your home - roses do not make good houseplants, so enjoy the blooms when they're on show, deadhead to encourage further blooms, keep watered but don't leave it sitting in water in the tray at the bottom. You can certainly pot it up into something bigger (certainly deeper) and it may last longer if you do - or it may not. If you have space outdoors, you could transfer it to the ground when the flowers are finished.